# Rails: Sending Emails with Dynamic Delivery Options is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

According to the documentation sending emails with dynamic delivery options works by passing the new delivery options hash as argument to mail()

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user, company)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                         password: company.smtp_password,
                         address: company.smtp_host }
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached",
         delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
  end
end
```

However the mail is still sent using the default delivery options defined in the environment config files e.g. production.rb or development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'ourdomain.com',
      :user_name => 'default@ourdomain.com',
      :password => ENV['DEFAULT_PASSWORD'],
      :authentication => 'login',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Rails 4.

Does anyone know where the problem might be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does anyone know why this it not working and answer provides the solution? According to the [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), both should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwriting the delivery method settings after the mail has been generated worked:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user, company)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                         password: company.smtp_password,
                         address: company.smtp_host }
    mail = mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached")

    mail.delivery_method.settings.merge!(delivery_options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```rb
# config/initializers/custom_smtp.rb

class Mail::CustomSMTP < Mail::SMTP
  def initialize(values)
    self.settings = DEFAULTS.with_indifferent_access.merge(values)
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :custom_smtp, Mail::CustomSMTP
```

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user, company)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                         password: company.smtp_password,
                         address: company.smtp_host }
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached",
         delivery_method: :custom_smtp,
         delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
  end
end
```